# Singleton injected in Interceptor multiple instantiations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jboss, jboss6.x

I am using JBoss EAP 6.4.10 in a project and I have set up a `@Singleton` with `@Startup`. This singleton is `@Inject`ed into an `@Interceptor` because I use some methods from it in the interceptor.

So far so good, it basically works, but what I noticed is that the `@PostConstruct` method of the `@Singleton` is not called once, nay it is called 496 times. So I wonder why this is happening. Cant I inject a singleton in an interceptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had imported `import javax.ejb.Singleton;` instead of `import javax.inject.Singleton;`